# C++ / Djinni Error Field type is an abstract class

Tags: c++, djinni

I'm making an app in React-native that uses Djinni from dropbox to bridge between C++ and Javascript. Calling from Javascript to C++ works well but now I'm implementing Call from C++ to Java/ObjC, my C++ skills are so and so. So I'm stuck on initialising class method.
I'm basing this on the example provided with Djinni.
AnotherClassMain is the access point from Javascript to C++.

I want to call runAProcess method from processAImpl inside anotherClassMain.

But I get the error
Field type 'aEditing::ProcessAImpl' is an abstract class
On the line ProcesAImpl  processA; in anotherClassMain.hpp

How can I access this initiate the class processAImpl and call the runAProcess from anotherClassMain ??

// processA.hpp created by djinni

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

namespace aEditing {
class ProcessA {
public:
    virtual ~ProcessA() {}
    virtual bool runThisProcess(const std::string & str) = 0;
};
}
```

//processAImpl.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "processA.hpp"

namespace aEditing {
class ProcessAImpl : public ProcessA {

public:
    ProcessAImpl(const std::shared_ptr<ProcessA> & listener);
    void runAProcess(const std::string aCommand);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<ProcessA> aProcess;
};
}
```

//processAImpl.cpp

```
#include "procesAImpl.hpp"
namespace aEditing {

ProcessAImpl::ProcessAImpl (const std::shared_ptr<ProcessA> & listener) {
    this->aProcess = listener;
}

void ProcessAImpl::runAProcess(const std::string aCommand) {
    this->aProcess->runThisProcess(aCommand);
}
}
```

//anotherClassMain.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "includes.hpp"
#include "processAImpl.hpp"

namespace anotherProcessing {

  class AnotherProcessingMain: public anotherProcessing::AnotherProcessing {
    public:
      AnotherProcessingMain();
      string anotherProcessing(const std::string &Input, const std::string &output) override;
    private:
        ProcesAImpl  processA;
  };
}
```

//anotherClassMain.cpp

```
#include "anotherClassMain.hpp"

namespace anotherProcessing {
  shared_ptr<AnotherProcessing> AnotherProcessing::create() {
    return make_shared<AnotherProcessingMain>();
  }

  AnotherProcessingMain::AnotherProcessingMain() {}

  string AnotherProcessingMain::anotherProcessing(const std::string &Input, const std::string &output){

    processA.runAProcess("testCommand");  //Trying to access this!

    return "yeah";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access this initiate the class `processAImpl` and call the `runAProcess` from anotherClassMain ??

I suppose you mean to **instantiate** the class `processAImpl`.
`ProcessA` is an abstract class because it contains a `pure virtual` function.
When you derive from an abstract class, you must implement that `pure virtual` function in the derived class. Otherwise you will not be able to instantiate the derived class.

So implement (provide a definition of) `runThisProcess(const std::string & str)` in the derived class `processAImpl`.

Comment: Yes mean to say instantiate :)
When I put under processAImpl.hpp
public: 
    virtual bool runThisProcess(const std::string & str);'

I still get the Error Field type is an abstract class.
If I set in anotherClassMain.hpp 
aEditing::ProcessAImpl processA; 
instead of 
ProcessAImpl processA;
I get Constructor for 'anotherProcessing::AnotherProcessingMain' must explicitly initialize the member 'processA' which does not have a default constructor

Comment: @user3840315: You have to provide a definition for it like `runThisProcess(const std::string & str) { //do stuff here }`

Comment: Thanks for your help, just not sure what I'm doing wrong, so I added as you said in processAImpl.hpp 
`bool runProcess(const std::string & str);`
And in processAImpl.cpp
 `bool ProcessAImpl::runProcess(const int &str){
} `

I get Unknown type name 'ProcessAImpl'; did you mean 'aEditing::ProcessAImpl'? in my anotherClassMain.hpp

Comment: @user3840315: Yes, specify the name of the namespace as well.

Comment: Then I get ` Constructor for 'anotherProcessing::AnotherProcessingMain' must explicitly initialize the member 'processA' which does not have a default constructor`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a declaration of the base classes pure virtual method `bool runThisProcess(const std::string &)`. Did you mean for `void ProcessAImpl::runAProcess(const string)` to be the implementation?

The name and argument types must **match exactly**

- `runThisProcess` vs `runAProcess`
- `const std::string &` vs `const string`

You should mark the methods in the subclass that you intend to be overriding base class methods as `override` (if there can be grandchildren classes) or `final` (if there can't), so that the compiler can better inform you of typos like this

You are also missing initialisation of `AnotherProcessingMain::processA`. You need something like

```
AnotherProcessingMain::AnotherProcessingMain()
  : processA(/* a const std::shared_ptr<ProcessA> & from somewhere */) 
{}
```

because the only constructor for `ProcessAImpl` you defined takes a `const std::shared_ptr<ProcessA> &`.

It is **very suspicious** that you have `ProcessAImpl` have a `std::shared_ptr<ProcessA>` member. There needs to be some class that *actually does stuff* in it's `runThisProcess` member, and it should probably be `ProcessAImpl`. As it currently stands, `ProcessAImpl` **does nothing**. You've basically got [turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down).

Comment: The arguments accidentally came up wrong when I wrote them here, but are correct in the code I'm running :).

Comment: @user3840315 does the name match?

Comment: When I match the name it still doesnt allow me to instantiate the class in anotherClassMain.hpp,

I added to processAImpl.hpp under public:
`bool runProcess(const std::string & str);`

And in processAImpl.cpp
`bool ProcessAImpl::runProcess(const std::string & str){ }`

And that gives me in anotherClassMain.hpp
`Unknown type name 'ProcessAImpl'; did you mean 'aEditing::ProcessAImpl'?`

Fix that and then I get 
`Constructor for 'anotherProcessing::AnotherProcessingMain' must explicitly initialize the member 'processA' which does not have a default constructor`

Comment: @user3840315 either add  a method `bool ProcessAImpl::runThisProcess(const std::string &)`, or remove the inheritance of `ProcessA`. You can't construct an object of a type that has a non-overridden pure virtual member

Comment: Sry meant to write `bool runThisProcess(const std::string & str); `  not `bool runProcess(const std::string & str);`

Comment: Is it possible you could give me an example of how to call runThisProcess in processA.hpp straight from anotherClassMain.cpp without going through processAImpl. I've tried in anotherClassMain.hpp to do `std::shared_ptr<ProcessA> aProcess;` and then in anotherClassMain.cpp I do `aProcess->runThisProcess("testCommand");` but I get a nullPtr.

Comment: @user3840315 You need *some class* that inherits from `ProcessA`, and has what you want in it's `runThisProcess` member. You then need to `std::make_shared<ThatClass>(/* args... */)` *somewhere*, and pass it to `AnotherProcessingMain` in `AnotherProcessing::create()`